# if $f:[1, \infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, if the limit $\int^\infty _1 f(x)dx$ exists then $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, functions

I have this:
if $f:[1, \infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ and the limit $\int^\infty _1 f(x)dx$ exists then $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$

How can I show this to be true, is it similar if it were $[0,\infty)$? Or am I incorrect in thinking this statement to be true?

Thanks to anyone, who can help!

Comment: Do you need the limit to exist?

Comment: It is well known that, unlike sequences, the existence of $\int_1^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ doesn't imply that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$. The lower bound in the integral is not important because we are only interested in the behaviour of $f$ at infinity.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102678/is-there-a-continuous-positive-function-whose-integral-over-0-infty-converg?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Also Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109826/function-whose-integral-over-0-infty-is-finite-but-the-limit-of-the-funct

Comment: Your statement is syntactically unclear (there are 2 "then"). So is your title (there are 2 "the").

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner yes, but it has to be 0

Comment: @Proloffc6 If you require the limit to exist, then please refer to the second link I posted earlier after "Also Related:".

Answer (score 0):

A counter example:
$$ \int_1^\infty \sin(x^2)dx $$
exists. However
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x^2) $$
doesn’t exist.