# $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ non-negative continuous integrable function. Can limit be nonzero (assuming it exists)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be non-negative continuous function such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f d\mu < \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \in [0, \infty]$ exists. Is it always the case $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$?

Edit: Measure being considered is the Lebesgue measure.

Attempt:

My initial thought is it is not true. I could try and take a "tent" function that is only non-zero on the integers, but shift it by a negative exponential. Similar to this example: [Is there a continuous positive function whose integral over $(0,\infty)$ converges but whose limit is not zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102678/is-there-a-continuous-positive-function-whose-integral-over-0-infty-converg?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But in the example above the limit does not exist.

Thanks.

Comment: If the limit $l$ is strictly positive, then $f(x) \gt l/2 \gt 0$ for $x$ large enough and the map can't be integrable.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I'm not seeing why that means the map can't be integrable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the measure you're considering? If it's the Lebesgue measure, then I think that assuming that the limit exists implies it is zero.

Suppose
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = L > 0.
$$

This means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, a value $x_{\varepsilon} > 0$ exists such that $\forall x > x_{\varepsilon}, \ \ \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon $.

Take $\varepsilon = {\frac L 2}$; for any $x > x_{\varepsilon}$ we have $f(x) > {\frac L 2}$.

Thus
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \ \text{d}\mu \ge  \int_{(x_{\varepsilon}, +\infty)} f(x) \ \text{d}\mu > \int_{(x_{\varepsilon}, +\infty)} {\frac L 2} \ \text{d}\mu = +\infty,
$$
which contradicts the hypothesis.

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks!